# If all real conjugacy classes are strongly real, then all real irreps are "strongly real"(symmetric), true?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, frobenius-schur-indicator, open-problems

**Question** Is true that if all real conjugacy classes of a finite group are strongly real, then all its real irreducible representations (irreps)  are "strongly real" (symmetric)? And *vice versa*?

**Definitions:**
An irrep is called real if its [Frobenius–Schur indicator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius%E2%80%93Schur_indicator) is either $+1$ or $-1$, but not $0$.
An irrep is called "symmetric" ("orthogonal" ("strongly real")) if it has FS-indicator $+1$, which is equivalent to it being possible to realize it over the real numbers.

A conjugacy class is called "real" if it is preserved by $g\mapsto g^{-1}$. It is called "strongly real" if it is a product of two involutions.

**Context** It is known that the number of real conjugacy classes is the same as the number of real irreps.  A. Knutson asked: [Are there “real” vs. “quaternionic” conjugacy classes in finite groups?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46900/are-there-real-vs-quaternionic-conjugacy-classes-in-finite-groups), i.e., is it possible to split "real" conjugacy classes into two subclasses corresponding to the splitting of irreps. Tim Dokchitser [answered](https://mathoverflow.net/a/46964/2383) that no such splitting may exist in general which will be automorphism covariant ….

The question above is weakening A. Knutson's question. It has been asked explicitly in the paper [Kulshrestha and Singh - Real elements and Schur indices of a group](https://web.archive.org/web/20190407071151/http://www.indianmathsociety.org.in/mathstudent2011.pdf) ([MSN](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2977506), [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.3933)), where the authors present some positive evidence for the question above. However, their examples do not cover GAP's SmallGroups List.

**SubQuestion** How difficult is it to check this in GAP?
(I just installed it, but never played.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is No. My source is Rod Gow's rather wonderful little paper "[Real-valued characters and the Schur index](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002186937690096X)" ([MSN](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=407121)). Let me quote from the introduction:

> It may happen that all elements of a
>   group are strongly real while the
>   group possesses real-valued characters
>   of Schur index 2. An example is
>   provided by the central product of
>   quaternion and dihedral groups of
>   order 8.

(The Schur index equals $2$ if and only if the Frobenius–Schur indicator equals $-1$.)

Answer (score 3):

On a related question, see [Kaur and Kulshrestha - Strongly real special $2$-groups](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/00927872.2013.865042) ([arXiv](http://lanl.arxiv.org/abs/1210.3790), [MSN](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3298127)), which also answers the converse question.